# Adding attributes to a generated object?

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I have defined a generator which generates Poisson arrival rates to the system. I want each generated arrival (customer)  has a random (x,y) which shows the location of the arrival customer to the system. i.e I want to generate Poisson arrival rate to the system where each arrival is coming from a random location. Let's assume x is in range 50 and y in range 60.

How can I add this to the following code?

```
class Arrival(object):

    def __init__(self, stream_defin, referrer):
        self.service = stream_defin["service"]
        self.arrival_rate = stream_defin["rate"]
        self.referrer = referrer

    def sim_init(self, env,sim_stats):
        self.sim_stats = sim_stats
        self.env = env
        self.env.process(self.sim_arrival_generator())

    def sim_arrival_generator(self):
            i = 0
            while True:
                interarrival = spstats.expon(scale=1/self.arrival_rate).rvs()
                yield self.env.timeout(interarrival)
                i+=1
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?  What here represents an arrival?  If `interarrival` is the arrival you speak of, why not just make that a dict, assign the delay you're computing to the key `delay`, and then also compute two random values for keys `x` and `y` in the dict to represent the random location.

Comment: Thanks Steve for the reply. It's a long code where I am trying to simulate arrivals and services in a company. Is there a better way to simulate Poisson arrivals to the system and add attributes to each single arrival to the system? –

Comment: Better way than what?  You don't show anything here.

Comment: If you wanted to simulate a Poisson arrival to the system where each single arrival has a  (x,y), how would you do it?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want, but let me try.  Since it's hard to put code in comments, I'll go ahead and put in an answer. If it isn't what you're looking for, I'll keep working on it or remove it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code refers to a number of objects and methods that you don't provide the definitions for.  This makes it hard to know what you're looking for exactly.  Plus, I'm not sure I even understand what you want conceptually.  But if I take the simplest interpretation of what you're asking for, here's what I'd suggest:

I assume that this line is currently creating an "arrival", which is referenced by the `interarrival` variable:

```
interarrival = spstats.expon(scale=1/self.arrival_rate).rvs()
```

This value seems to currently be a delay value such that the pattern of successive delays covers a Poisson distribution pattern.  Rather than just a time value, you want at this point in your code to be creating a delay along with a random position given by `x` and `y` coordinates, and have these together represent an "arrival".

What I would suggest is to create a Python dictionary object to represent each arrival.  Here's how you could do that:

```
interarrival = {
    'delay': spstats.expon(scale=1 / self.arrival_rate).rvs(),
    'position': {
        'x': random.randint(self.min_x, self.max_x),
        'y': random.randint(self.min_y, self.max_y)
    }
}
```

Doing a bunch of coding work in an answer isn't what S.O. is really about, but you caught me at a moment of boredom, and I hate providing code I haven't actually run, so...

I took a lot of liberties and filled out your code so that it would actually run and "do something", although all it does is delay between arrivals and print the value of each arrival as it comes through.  I assumed you wanted to see an actual delay because of your call to `self.env.timeout` and because your generator never stops generating arrivals.  Without the delay or some time consuming processing, this code would quickly spew thousands of arrivals that you couldn't read.

I renamed your class from `Arrival` to `Arrivals` because the code within deals with a stream of arrivals, not a single arrival, and I couldn't think of a good way to change that without making many more changes.  I tried to mostly add code, and change as little of your provided code as possible.  With all this in mind, here's what I came up with:

```
import scipy.stats as spstats
import random
import json
import time

class Arrivals(object):

    def __init__(self, stream_defin, referrer):
        self.service = stream_defin["service"]
        self.arrival_rate = stream_defin["rate"]
        self.min_x, self.max_x = stream_defin["min_x"], stream_defin["max_x"]
        self.min_y, self.max_y = stream_defin["min_y"], stream_defin["max_y"]
        self.referrer = referrer

    def sim_init(self, env, sim_stats):
        self.sim_stats = sim_stats
        self.env = env
        self.env.process(self.sim_arrival_generator())
        return self

    def sim_arrival_generator(self):
            i = 0
            while True:
                interarrival = {
                    'index': i,
                    'delay': spstats.expon(scale=1 / self.arrival_rate).rvs(),
                    'position': {
                        'x': random.randint(self.min_x, self.max_x),
                        'y': random.randint(self.min_y, self.max_y)
                    }
                }
                yield self.env.timeout(interarrival)
                i += 1

class Env():
    def process(self, arrivals):
        for arrival in arrivals:
            # Do whatever needs to be done with each arrival
            print('Processing arrival: ')
            print(json.dumps(arrival, indent=4))

    def timeout(self, arrival):
        # Delay the arrival by its delay time before delivering for processing
        print("Delaying %2.2f seconds..." % (arrival['delay']))
        time.sleep(arrival['delay'])
        return arrival

def main():

    stream_defin = {
        'service': 'service',

        'rate': 0.5,

        'min_x': 5,
        'max_x': 50,
        'min_y': 10,
        'max_y': 60
    }

    stats = [] # a place to collect results, I assume
    Arrivals(stream_defin, 'referrer').sim_init(Env(), stats)

main()
```

This thing runs forever, so you have to CTRL-C out of it when you want to stop it.  It would be easy to add an `iterations` config value to limit the number of iterations. You could either add this to the generator itself, or just break out of the `process()` method when the specified iteration count is reached.

Sample results (with actual delays in output as noted):

```
Delaying 5.39 seconds...
Processing arrival: 
{
    "index": 0,
    "delay": 5.394974068076859,
    "position": {
        "x": 34,
        "y": 29
    }
}
Delaying 1.51 seconds...
Processing arrival: 
{
    "index": 1,
    "delay": 1.5095025601339542,
    "position": {
        "x": 24,
        "y": 24
    }
}
Delaying 1.48 seconds...
Processing arrival: 
{
    "index": 2,
    "delay": 1.4840036046166114,
    "position": {
        "x": 28,
        "y": 57
    }
}
Delaying 4.09 seconds...
Processing arrival: 
{
    "index": 3,
    "delay": 4.08649062133332,
    "position": {
        "x": 37,
        "y": 14
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much Steve for your help, I really appreciate it and I'm sorry if I couldn't put the whole code as I don't have the permission to do that.